# Is it efficient to use copy-expensive class as the mapped value in std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, std

In a nutshell, is it efficient to use

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> > instead of
std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int>>?
```

For vector, i will choose boost::shared_ptr. But for std::map, I am not sure whether it is worthwhile.

Comment: In general, it is the cost of the _move-constructor_ rather than the cost of _copy-constructor_ which will have a major effect on performance. If you are concerned about performance then profile your program. Efficiency depends on too many factors to give a general answer, and is often more to do with simply not doing work than the specific data-structures that you use. The real thing to be concerned about here is that `boost::shared_ptr` gives a less accurate representation of the actual lifetimes of the `set`s, and will lead to more awkward syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for `std::map::insert()` says http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

For `std::map::erase()` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

which means that either insert nor erase does not move objects around, so you should not worry about expense of copy, except the case that you need to insert already created big object into a map. But in this case I would use `std::map::emplace()` method and/or move semantics rather than complicating code with shared pointer.